# Modify the_content after the more tag

Tags: plugins, the-content, read-more

I have created a custom plugin that pulls video and images out of a post and puts them into a nicely formatted set of galleries.  The only problem is that the plugin doesn't allow me to put a video or image before the more tag without creating a mini gallery.  Is there a name or way to adjust my plugin to make it only read the_content that comes AFTER the more tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use the [`get_extended( $post )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_extended) function; that returns an array with different parts of the content. See this example which works inside the Loop:

```
$content_arr = get_extended( get_the_content() ); 
var_dump( $content_arr );
echo $content_arr['main'];  //Display the part before the more tag
```

Comment: @Hunter Then please mark it as _solution_ (the check mark below the voting arrows on the left). Thanks.

Comment: I have logged in and there are no arrows that allow me to mark as a solution. I also can't upvote your answer.

Comment: @HunterNelson your question belonged to duplicate "unregistered" account. I merged it for you and you should be able to accept answer now.